# Nodejs- Manipulating properties while destructuring

Tags: node.js, data-manipulation, destructuring

I am looking for a smart way to manipulate data while I'm destructuring an object.
Take a look on the following code:

```
let employee =  {
   name: 'John Doe',
   birthday: '1980/01/01', // yyyy/MM/dd format
   department: 'R&D'
}

const { name, birthday, department } = employee

console.log(`${name} is working under ${department} and their birthday is on ${birthday}.`)
```

Let's say I want to adjust this to show their age instead of their birthday, I have a method that calculates how old they are, which is called `calcAge`.

I'm expecting the code to revolve around this (or equivalent to):

```
let employee =  {
   name: 'John Doe',
   birthday: '1980/01/01', // yyyy/MM/dd format
   department: 'R&D'
}

// Option 1: Current state:
const { name, birthday , department } = employee
const age = calcAge(birthday)

// Option 2: Required state:
// const { name, age: calcAge(birthday), department } = employee
// Note this:    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

console.log(`${name} is working under ${department} and they are ${age} years old.`)
```

Hope this makes sense, if you have any questions please feel free to ask.

Comment: You can mark the question as solve of it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to manipulate the data while you are destructuring an object. The only purpose of the assignment destructuring is to be able to assign values and not manipulate them.

Also, manipulate data during the assignment destructuring could lead to confusion and hard readability.

Comment: Thank you for your response!
Is there any link I can read more about this?

Comment: you can have explanation and example there https://codeburst.io/es6-destructuring-the-complete-guide-7f842d08b98f